# cant display .svg as backgroundimage

Tags: css, mobile, svg, screen-resolution

I'm trying to create a little HTML5 mobile game. To avoid any problems with screenresolution I'm using .svg as backgroundimages. While working on the local server the images don't get displayed on the final server: http://tangera.bemoredifferent.com/. It would be great if anybody has a solution for this problem.

Daniel

Answer (score 1):

If you like to use .svg file as background, you must add below code in your stylesheet

```
    background-size: cover;
```

Reason why, see the documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-size

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/c9LgV/

Good Luck !

Comment: I think I have a different problem. While using the right CSS the server is sending the wrong mime- type. Tryed to solve this problem with some changes in the `.htaccess` but it still dosen't work. Any idea how to set the right mimetype without dynamically change all .svg's with PHP?